# iPhone Issue with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier in custom cell with textfield delete value

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a problem with my cell textfield values when scrolling on a UITableView. When I scroll down and hide a custom cell, the value of the textField is deleted. The dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method doesn't work. I have this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 static NSString *SectionsTableIdentifier = @"MyCustomCell";

 MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

 cell.labelCustomAttribute.text= @"Attribute Name";
 cell.textFieldCustomAttribute.delegate = self;

 return cell;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to register the custom cell with the tableView in the viewDidLoad method and then simply use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. If you register the cell, the dequeue method will automatically pick up a reusable cell OR allocate a new custom cell (if none is available).

Example:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Get a point to the customized table view cell for MyCustomCell
    UINib *myCustomCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustomCell" bundle:nil];
    // Register the MyCustomCell with tableview
    [[self tableView] registerNib:myCustomCellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCustomCell"];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *SectionsTableIdentifier = @"MyCustomCell";
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier];

    cell.labelCustomAttribute.text= @"Attribute Name";
    cell.textFieldCustomAttribute.delegate = self;

    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally the reuseIdentifier is assigned in the UITableViewCell's `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method, which you are not using because you are loading your view from a Nib.

You cannot set this property after because it is read only.

Maybe you can try instanciating the cell using the standard `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` and add the view from your Nib as a subview of the cell's ContentView...

Now what is happening in your case is that you create a new cell every time that the Table View needs to display one. Clearly, this is not going to work. Actually, if you were reusing cells, you would have to also store the content of your text field somewhere (preferably in your data source) and put it when you reuse the cell. If you do not store it, when the cell is going to be reused, it will contain the data from the previous row in which it was displayed.

Comment: How make that tag value is save?